# Loop through and manipulate array of strings in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to check redirects for a bunch of my URLs via the following command:

```
curl -v -L http://<my-url> 2>&1 | grep -i "^< location:" | head -n 1
```

and it works as expected by returning the following output:

```
< Location: https://<my-url>:443/
```

Since I have a bunch of URLs I want to check, I wrote a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a domains=("http://my-url1.com" "http://my-url2.com" "http://my-url3.com")

for i in "${domains[@]}"
do 
 curl -v -L http://${i} 2>&1 | grep -i "^< location:" | head -n 1
done
```

But when I run the script via `./my-script.sh` I am not seeing the output like `< Location: https://<my-url>:443/`

How can I get the following output?

```
< Location: https://<my-url1>:443/
< Location: https://<my-url2>:443/
< Location: https://<my-url2>:443/
and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `http://` in both `http://${i}` and the array of domains. When `${i}` is expanded it results in invalid URLs such as `http://http://my-url1.com`.